# Make .bat silent and automatic

Tags: windows, batch-file, backup, xcopy

long story short I have a set up that takes pictures every few minutes and saves them. For backup purposes and to keep my flash drive up to date I wrote a short .bat to copy the files every hour

```
'@echo off
:start
XCOPY "C:\Users\name\pictures\*.bmp" "D:\backup" /q /y
TIMEOUT /t 3600 /nobreak
goto start'
```

`
However, i would like to make this automatically start(can i just copy it to the startup folder?) and I would like to make it run silently, no open terminal.

Comment: Set up the batch file to run every hour with Task Scheduler.  Then tell it to run even when the user is not logged in.  This runs the batch file in the background then.  If configure the task to run only when the user is logged in, you will see the cmd window.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the fact that this sounds like someone trying to steal pics in a way that is not above board, I think that you would probably have better luck with the Windows Task Scheduler. That way you could schedule the copy and it will happen even after the computer reboots.

Comment: Believe what you want but I have a few webcam based wildlife cameras set up as part of my environmental studies project and I want to hide the DOS and automate the back up. thank you

Comment: Most admin/backup operations can be used to violate privacy or laws; this is not the place for moral discussion. Let us help the person and trust they will use sound judgement.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to run it silently from a vbs script

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "loaction of bat as c:\folder\script.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Got this from a quick google, and im not possible to test it as of now but i can return in 2 and a half hours with a better answer if its not working right.